# Vectorized SciPy ode solver

Tags: python, scipy, ode

My question is with respect to the current scipy ode solver. From the [scipy doc page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html#scipy.integrate.ode), their usage is:

```
# A problem to integrate and the corresponding jacobian:

from scipy.integrate import ode
y0, t0 = [1.0j, 2.0], 0
def f(t, y, arg1):
    return [1j*arg1*y[0] + y[1], -arg1*y[1]**2]
def jac(t, y, arg1):
    return [[1j*arg1, 1], [0, -arg1*2*y[1]]]

# The integration:
r = ode(f, jac).set_integrator('zvode', method='bdf', with_jacobian=True)
r.set_initial_value(y0, t0).set_f_params(2.0).set_jac_params(2.0)
t1 = 10
dt = 1
while r.successful() and r.t < t1:
    r.integrate(r.t+dt)
    print("%g %g" % (r.t, r.y))
```

My problem is: it is using a lot of the python loops (the while-loop) which essentially slows the program down. I can try to write a C code and use ctypes to make it faster, but I won't be able to access the nice algorithms like dopri5 in scipy (unless I implement it myself).

Is there any vectorized way of coding to make this faster?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'vectorization' means doing a bunch of calculations in parallel, all at once.  Yes, the detailed implementation will involve iteration, but it's in `C` and the order does not matter to you, the `Python` programmer.

But an ode solution like this is essentially a serial operation.  You have to solve the problem at time `t` before you solve it at time `t+dt`.  You can't vectorize the solution through time.  The best you can do is choose an `ode` solver that makes intelligent choices for the time steps (`dt`), big steps where possible, small ones when needed to capture rapid changes.

A good ode solver lets you vectorize the spatial dimension - i.e.  solving 10 odes in parallel.  You might also be able to vectorize calculating the Jacobian, returning both `y+dy` and `y-dy` at once.  Basically you want to make the calculation of `f` and `jac` as fast as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes total sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit late, but I think what you need is [scipy.integrate.odeint](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html). It takes an array of time points and computes the solution at each of them. This makes the loop to be computed outside Python (in FORTRAN).

Comment: Never too late man! This is what I ended up using, and others looking at this post in the future may find it helpful. Thanks a lot!